# "Left dislocation" of object for emphasis

Tags: verbs, inversion, subjects, objects

> *I admire her.* (SVO).
>
> *Her I admire.* (OSV).
>
> The **left dislocation** of the object is due to *emphasis* on it.

**"I know when he will come."**

Here, the object is *"when he will come"*.
Is 'left dislocation' possible here and can we say the following?

**"When he will come I know."**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's technically possible, but since the object being dislocated is a clause instead of a single word, it's much more jarring and potentially confusing. This is probably something a learner should avoid.

If you spoke this sentence, you would need to pay close attention to your tone and emphasis, stressing "When" by raising the pitch of your voice, inserting a very slight pause before "I" and then lightly stressing "know" (not as stressed as "when"). In writing, you might need to put "When" in italics and even to insert a comma after "come" to demarcate the clauses. These measures help the listener/ reader correctly parse the sentence since the word order is not the usual one.

Comment: As a stand-alone sentence, it's not really possible. It needs to be in strong contrast to something else. For instance, "_When_ he will come, I know. But _why_ he is coming is a mystery." (I am not disagreeing with your answer -- I am just supplementing it.)

Comment: I'd also add that it's a good idea to comma separate even single words that you intend to left dislocate in this manner.  I assume the OP got the example from a textbook, but even that example feels so wrong without a comma.  "Her, I admire" is much more easily parsed and understood than "Her I admire", and it better matches how we would say it out loud.